# Docker push, repeats pushing a layer for ever

Tags: docker

I'm running a docker push command on a large image. 15GB.
When the push of the large layer ends, reaches the full size, it starts to push the same layer again and again.

Example:
Starts pushing:
....
ebdf700cf459: Layer already exists
89114e3edfaa: Pushing [================================>       ]   13.7GB/15.78GB
....

Reaches the size:
ebdf700cf459: Layer already exists
89114e3edfaa: Pushing [==================================================>]  15.81GB

Thinking:
ebdf700cf459: Layer already exists
89114e3edfaa: Pushing [==================================================>]  15.81GB

Then a retry:
89114e3edfaa: Pushing [=====>                                          ]  1.743GB/15.78GB

Do you have any idea how to address such an issue?

Thank you.

Comment: My past experience has been that layers above about 1 GB do not reliably transfer across the network, in either direction.  Can you break the layer into smaller pieces, or keep whatever very large content is there outside the image?

Comment: @David, sadly no, it is an installed product that I cannot break into smaller parts. Previously, it worked with no issues. It seems that it completes the push, but then at the end, it decides to retry.